# How can I know if a zookeeper node is a persistent node or a ephemeral one?

Tags: nodes, apache-zookeeper, persistent

As the title says, how can I know if a zookeeper data node is a persistent node or an ephemeral one from zkCli? It seems that the zkCli.sh doesn't show any commands which can help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following two command to check if a node is persistent node or an ephemeral

[How to get the create mode of a path in zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052422/how-to-get-the-create-mode-of-a-path-in-zookeeper/25134264#25134264)

```
stat path
get path -s
```

Ex:

```
stat /config/node1 
get /config/node1 -s
```

Similar to above you will get a stat structure in CLI as well. You can check the "ephermalowner" property of the stat. This corresponds to session id of the owner of this znode if the znode is an ephemeral node. If it is not an ephemeral node, it will be zero.

Example output of persistent and ephemeral nodes

**Persistent**

```
cZxid = 0x22
ctime = Tue Nov 03 17:21:34 IST 2020
mZxid = 0x22
mtime = Tue Nov 03 17:21:34 IST 2020
pZxid = 0x27
cversion = 5
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 17
numChildren = 5
```

**Ephemeral**

```
cZxid = 0xc1
ctime = Tue Nov 03 18:11:06 IST 2020
mZxid = 0xc1
mtime = Tue Nov 03 18:11:06 IST 2020
pZxid = 0xc1
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x1001ca8fc21001c
dataLength = 0
numChildren = 0
```